# Lower bound for polynomial with complex coefficient

Tags: inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $p(z)=z^{n}+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_{1}z+a_{0}$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients. Define $R:=1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|a_k|$. Show that $|p(z)| > R$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$ with $|z|>R$.

Any hints or solution will be appreciated.

Comment: @Alex
Thanks I was able to prove it, assuming $n \geq 2$.
For $n = 1$, this statement is not necessary true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Having $|z|>R$ try to estimate from below the difference $|z^n|-|a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots+a_1z+a_0|$.